# In Simonini reaction how does the $2:1$ ratio of reagents enable formation of ester as major product?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

The Wikipedia article on Simonini reaction says:

> The ratio of the reagents play an
>   important role in the determination of products, namely, if $1:1$
>   ratio of salt and iodine is used alkyl iodide is formed. On the other
>   hand, a $2:1$ ratio gives $\ce{RCOOR}$ and $3:2$ ratio gives both the
>   products.

For $1:1$ ratio I understood why alkyl iodide is formed (found the mechanism [here](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/hunsdiecker-reaction.shtm)). But for $2:1$ ratio why is ester formed as major product ?

Comment: This is the Wikipedia article from which I have taken the quoted lines and the image  in the question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunsdiecker_reaction#Simonini_reaction

Answer (score 1):

If you have the extra equivalent of the carboxylate, then this carboxylate will never react with iodine to form the alkyl iodide. Instead, it will do the next best thing, which is $S_{\mathrm{N}}2$ reaction with the alkyl iodide that you did make.

Note that this probably only works if **R** is primary.